# C++: not all values are written into the .txt file

Tags: c++

I have a bug in my program written in C++. It deals with two .txt files. Imports values from one (word.txt), and has to filter and add them sorted into another file - text3.txt.

In txt file word.txt there are following entries:

```
Dora cat 7
John human 28
Bark dog 12
Steven human 56
Rex dog 15
```

p«b«endl; should add text into text3.txt text file from word.txt with specific order. First everybody with "human" and then everybody with "dog" (with "cat" it doesn't need to add).

At the moment, only last one is added into the file, all "dog" entries.

Can you please help me to understand where is the problem?

```
 #include "stdafx.h"
 #include <stdio.h>
 #include<stdlib.h>
 #include <fstream>
 #include <iostream>
 using namespace std;


 char *b;
 char *u;
 char *p;

 int getl(char c[1024],char num[10],char add[10],char ad[10])
 {
    u=&add[0];
    p=&ad[0];
    ifstream u("slovo.txt");
    ofstream p("text3.txt");
    b= &c[0];

    while(u.getline(b,1024))
    {
       if (strstr(b,num))
       {
          p«b«endl;
          cout«b«endl;
       }
    }

    return(0);
 }


 int _tmain()
 {
    char n[1024];
    char str[] ="chelovek";
    char nimi[]="imd";
    char nick[]="omd";
    printf("\nCHELOVEK\n\n");
    getl(n,str,nimi,nick);

    char m[1024];
    char stri[] ="sobaka";
    char nimii[]="omd";
    char nicki[]="amd";
    printf("\nSOBAKA\n\n");
    getl(m,stri,nimii,nicki);
 }
```

Thank you.

Comment: can you please properly indent your code?

Comment: The code seems pretty unrelated to your problem statement. At least I cannot find any "dog" or "human" in the code.

Comment: You have a single character `«` instead of two characters `<<`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You use the same output file at both calls. So all previous records of humans are replaced by records of dogs. Use `std::ios::app` when opening your file to append at end.

```
#include <fstream>

std::ofstream out;

// std::ios::app is the open mode "append" meaning
// new data will be written to the end of the file.
out.open("myfile.txt", std::ios::app);

std::string str = "I am here.";
out << str;
```

**Advices** : you should really use mechanisms offered by C++ such as `std::string`, and avoid global variables and pointers. Also, name your variables clearly. By doing such, you could simplify your code 10x times at least.

And also, not everybody here understand Russian, so change the submitted code so everybody can understand that *chelovek* is *human*.